# Best style for maintaining long equation

Tags: python, coding-style

What do you think is the best way of writing this method for calculating an [ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) value? This function incorporates several 'short cuts' to the simplest method of calculating the value that speeds the calculation up considerably by reducing the amount of recursive calls, but you end up with a long expression.

The versions use:

- The line continuation character \
- Bracketed nested functions
- A single outer set of braces

Does any version seem better to you? why? I'm curious.

```
>>> def ack4(M, N):
   return (N + 1)            if M == 0 else \
          (N + 2)            if M == 1 else \
          (2*N + 3)          if M == 2 else \
          (8*(2**N - 1) + 5) if M == 3 else \
          ack4(M-1, 1)       if N == 0 else \
          ack4(M-1, ack4(M, N-1))

>>> def ack2(M, N):
   return (N + 1)            if M == 0 else (
          (N + 2)            if M == 1 else (
          (2*N + 3)          if M == 2 else (
          (8*(2**N - 1) + 5) if M == 3 else (
          ack2(M-1, 1)       if N == 0 else
          ack2(M-1, ack2(M, N-1))))))

>>> def ack3(M, N):
   return ((N + 1)            if M == 0 else
           (N + 2)            if M == 1 else
           (2*N + 3)          if M == 2 else
           (8*(2**N - 1) + 5) if M == 3 else
           ack3(M-1, 1)       if N == 0 else
           ack3(M-1, ack3(M, N-1)))

>>> ack2(4, 2) == ack3(4, 2) == ack4(4, 2)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def ack5(m, n):
    if m == 0: return n + 1
    if m == 1: return n + 2
    if m == 2: return 2*n + 3
    if m == 3: return 8*(2**n - 1) + 5
    if n == 0: return ack5(m-1, 1)
    return ack5(m-1, ack5(m, n-1))
```

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with just nesting in a simple elif chain?

```
def ack5(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return (n + 1)
    elif m == 1:
        return (n + 2)
    elif m == 2:
        return (2 * n + 3)
    elif m == 3:
        return (8 * ( 2 ** n - 1) + 5)
    elif n == 0:
        return ack5(m - 1, 1)
    else:
        return ack5(m - 1, ack5(m, n - 1))
```

Python code should be readable for the programmer, so it's more of a personal choice question. If I had to pick one of your 3 examples I'd go with ack4 since those backslashes indicate that everything is one big statement without bloating the expression like a bracket does in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Don't be afraid of multiple returns. Also, try to avoid capital letters for local variables.

```
def ack4(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return n + 1
    if m == 1:
        return n + 2
    if m == 2:
        return 2 * n + 3
    if m == 3:
        return (8 * ( 2 ** n - 1) + 5)
    if n == 0:
        return ack5(m - 1, 1)
    return ack5(m - 1, ack5(m, n - 1))
```